# What kind of dll or lib can be searched without setting the Linker->General->Additional Library Directories

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, linker

For example, Setupapi.lib can be searched when I set it to **Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies**. However, I haven't set the search path based on  **Linker->General->Additional Library Directories**.
Here comes the question:

1. What kind of dll or lib can be searched directly.
2. If there is a default file path, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything in the directories set by the VC++ Directories > Library Directories setting.  The $(WindowsSDK_LibraryPath_x86) in the case of Setupapi.lib.  Whose value is in turn determined by the project's selected Toolset and retrieved from the registry.

VS2008 is old and used a very different build engine.  No Toolset setting yet, the Tools + Options, Projects and Solutions, VC++ Directories setting mattered back then.  IIRC, it was set to the SDK v6.0 install directory.